# Is it a bad thing to transfer all logs internally output by a smartphone application to the cloud?

Tags: privacy

I am a developer of an application for smart phones. The language is flutter, but it is not directly related to this question.

We are getting general crash logs, but there are cases where the behavior is not a crash, but the behavior is not right.
To investigate this, we would like to forward all the logs that the app is outputting to a cloud like AWS CloudWatch even if there are no errors, is this logically permissible?

( This question is not asking about a method to steal "other app's" logs that the customer's Android or iPhone is outputting.
Technically, there is nothing hackish about it, just replacing the processing of the method that outputs the logs and posting it to the server.)

My biggest concern is privacy issues.
We currently use firebase crashlytics to send crash logs, and I am sure this is done routinely by many apps.
However, I cannot be confident that transmitting all logs independent of crashes is logically, socially, or Google and Apple-acceptable.
Logically, one could argue that since the crash logs are transmitted, there is no problem with transmitting the logs that the app produces as an extension of the crash logs.

Please share your actual experiences or blog posts of apps you are running that do something similar.
Or, if you have had a big problem with sending all logs to the server in the same way, please let us know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do understand the need to extend crash log collection to all logs for better app maintenance, but that will demand careful handling in order to abide by legal, ethical, and policy guidelines:

### Legal and Compliance Considerations

- **[Data Minimization](https://edps.europa.eu/data-protection/data-protection/glossary/d_en#data_minimization)**: According to best practices and regulations such as the General Data Protection Regulation (GDPR), you should only collect data that is strictly necessary for the purpose it is being collected for.
- **[User Consent](https://edps.europa.eu/data-protection/data-protection/glossary/c_en#consent)**: It is essential to obtain informed consent from users explicitly indicating that the application would be collecting and transferring logs to the cloud.
- **[Transparency](https://gdpr-info.eu/recitals/no-58/)**: Maintain transparency with users by clearly stating the purpose of collecting such data in your privacy policy.

### Technical Considerations

- **Data Security**: Ensure that the data transfer happens over secure channels (like HTTPS) and that the data is stored securely in the cloud.
  (For me, the challenge was to know *where* those data are stored, in which data center, in Europe or outside?)
- **Anonymisation**: Implement measures to anonymize the data to protect user privacy.
  See "[10 MISUNDERSTANDINGS RELATED TO ANONYMISATION](https://edps.europa.eu/system/files/2021-04/21-04-27_aepd-edps_anonymisation_en_5.pdf)" (PDF) like:

  - "Pseudonymisation is the same as anonymisation"
  - "Encryption is anonymisation"
  - "Anonymisation of data is always possible"
  - "Anonymisation is forever"
  - "Anonymisation always reduces the probability of re-identification of a dataset to zero"
  - "Anonymisation is a binary concept that cannot be measured"
  - "Anonymisation can be fully automated"
  - "Anonymisation makes the data useless"
  - "Following an anonymisation process that others used successfully will lead our organisation to equivalent results"
  - "There is no risk and no interest in finding out to whom this data refers to"

#### Apple and Google's Policies

Continually check for adherence to the policies of app stores, as they tend to update frequently.

- [Android and Google Play deadlines](https://developer.android.com/distribute/play-policies)
- [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/)

You can find [many illustrations](https://scholar.google.fr/scholar?q=gdpr+%22data+security%22&hl=fr&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart) on the challenges regarding log collection.
One example: "[Privacy, Data Sharing, and Data Security Policies of Women’s mHealth Apps: Scoping Review and Content Analysis](https://mhealth.jmir.org/2022/5/e33735)"

> Many of the most popular women’s mHealth apps on the market have poor data privacy, sharing, and security standards. Although regulations exist, such as the European Union General Data Protection Regulation, current practices do not follow them. The failure of the assessed women’s mHealth apps to meet basic data privacy, sharing, and security standards is not ethically or legally acceptable.
> 3. **[Log Filtering](https://www.papertrail.com/solution/tips/a-guide-to-log-filtering-tips-for-it-pros/)**: It would be logical to have mechanisms in place to filter logs and avoid transmitting sensitive or personal data.

#### Social and Ethical Considerations

1. **Trust**: Excessive data collection can lead to a trust deficit with users. It is prudent to weigh the technical benefits against potential negative perceptions.
   See for illustration the all debate around "[telemetry in the Go toolchain](https://github.com/golang/go/discussions/58409)"
2. **[Ethical Handling](https://dataprivacy.foxrothschild.com/2021/04/articles/european-union/gdpr/the-benefits-of-gdpr-compliance-and-ethical-handling-of-data/)**: Ensure ethical handling of user data, committing to not sharing the data with third parties without explicit consent.
   Avoid [dark patterns](https://www.termsfeed.com/blog/dark-patterns/).

#### Apple and Google's Policies

Continually check for adherence to the policies of app stores, as they tend to update frequently.

- [Android and Google Play deadlines](https://developer.android.com/distribute/play-policies)
- [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/)

You can find [many illustrations](https://scholar.google.fr/scholar?q=gdpr+%22data+security%22&hl=fr&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart) on the challenges regarding log collection.
One example: "[Privacy, Data Sharing, and Data Security Policies of Women’s mHealth Apps: Scoping Review and Content Analysis](https://mhealth.jmir.org/2022/5/e33735)"

> Many of the most popular women’s mHealth apps on the market have poor data privacy, sharing, and security standards. Although regulations exist, such as the European Union General Data Protection Regulation, current practices do not follow them. The failure of the assessed women’s mHealth apps to meet basic data privacy, sharing, and security standards is not ethically or legally acceptable.

---

As [jessehouwing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/736079/jessehouwing) added in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77112456/is-it-a-bad-thing-to-transfer-all-logs-internally-output-by-a-smartphone-applica/77125120#comment135963136_77125120):

> A number of apps I use offer a "**feedback**" option with the ability to gather additional logs to upload to the developer.
> I have to check an extra checkbox to permit the app to do that.
>
> Some apps pop-up a window when they encounter a strange state and ask for permission to upload logs.
> Most apps offer a way to see what is uploaded prior to upload.
> I like this model

Comment: A number of apps I use offer a "feedback" option with the ability to gather additional logs to upload to the developer. I have to check an extra checkbox to permit the app to do that. Some apps pop-up a window when they encounter a strange state and ask for permission to upload logs. Most apps offer a way to see what is uploaded prio to upload. I like this model.

Comment: @jessehouwing True, that seems a sensible implementation of that policy.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful response. I now understand the problem. And thank you for your reply in your comment. I had completely forgotten about the idea of a feedback function.

Comment: @Fushihara No problem. I have included jessehouwing's comment in the answer for more visibility.